# JS/jQuery - Use of global event handlers over individual event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have JS code wherein I am using global event handlers. What I mean by global event handlers is:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'my-class') {
    return e.target.className + ' has been clicked';
  }
  if (e.target.id === "id1") {
    return e.target.id + ' has been clicked';
  }
}
```

I was using individual event handlers - example is as follows:

```
$('.my-class').on('click', function(e) {
  return this + ' has been clicked';
}
$('#id1').on('click', function(e) {
  return this + ' has been clicked';
}
```

but was running into problems in regards to `if and/or` statements in the handlers, and in an effort not to right duplicative code, switched over to a global event handler - example with `if and/or` is this:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'my-class' || e.target.className === 'my-other-class') {
    return e.target.className + ' has been clicked';
  }
  if (e.target.id === "id1") {
    return e.target.id + ' has been clicked';
  }
}
```

(this is how it would look on individual handlers)

```
$('.my-class').on('click', function(e) {
  return this + ' has been clicked';
}
$('.my-other-class').on('click', function(e) {
  return this + ' has been clicked';
}
$('#id1').on('click', function(e) {
  return this + ' has been clicked';
}
```

However, now I am running into the problem where my code is getting quite complex and I am using `e.target`,`e.currentTarget`,`$(e.target).children()` ,etc. - even `$(e.target).parents()[i]` in a `for loop` which looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $(e.target).parents().length; i++) {
  if ($(e.target).parents()[i].className === 'my-class') {
    return 'this is annoying';
  }
}
```

which can get very confusing.

**I want to switch back to individual handlers (unless I really should use global handlers) but don't know how to handle the `if and/or` parts by using individual handlers**

Does anyone know a way to overcome this, or be able to give some insight into how I should structure my event handlers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and have jQuery do the work for you:

```
$(document).on('click', '.my-class, .my-other-class', function() {
   // handle my-class and my-other-class clicks
});
```

Also, within your handlers, `this` is bound to `event.target`, so you can simplify a bit to `$(this).hasClass('foo')`, `this.id === 'bar'` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your fast anaswer. so then would you have something which looks like this: `$(document).on('click', '.my-class, .my-other-class', function() {// handle my-class and my-other-class clicks}); $(document).on('click', '#id1', function() {
   // handle id1 clicks
});`this is what I understand from your code and the link you gave

Comment: or would it be more like $(document).on('click', '#id1, .my-class, .my-other-class', function() { //if (this.id === #id1); if($(this).hasClass('my-class')), etc. });

Answer (score 4):

Please check `if` statement. You have to write two 'equal'  == , you wrote only one time.

```
if (e.target.className == 'my-class' || e.target.className == 'my-other-class') {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would never use `document` as a selector for a click event. It would lead to confusion if you ask me. I would do something like this if you want the same behaviour for these elements:

```
$('.class1, .class2, #id1').on('click', function () {
    return $(this).attr('class') || $(this).attr('id');
 });
```